Specify np.ndarray and torch.tensor as two options for a dtype
I would like to specify two options for a datatype for a variable. Something like this:
class MyDataClass:

    MyData: np.ndarray | torch.float

    def __init__(self, as_torch):
        MyData = np.arange(1,10)
        if as_torch:
            MyData = torch.from_numpy(MyData)


... but this throws an error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'torch.dtype'
I think it would be possible to just not assign a datatype to MyData, but I was wondering if there's  a better solution.
What is the best practice to work around this error or solve this? Thanks in advance!
Tried:
np.ndarray | torch.tensor

You need to use a type for type hinting, not torch.float. If you'd use torch.dtype (torch.float is of type torch.dtype), it'd work but you don't want that presumably. As you want a numpy array or torch tensor, you'd want to use torch.Tensor (note the capital T) i.e.:
MyData: np.ndarray | torch.Tensor

FWIW, torch.tensor is a function, not a type. All torch tensors are of type torch.Tensor.

Also, np.ndarray is a generic type with two type parameters (matching the types of  .shape and .dtype), which should be provided. E.g. as np.ndarray[tuple[int], np.dtype[np.floating[Any]]].

You can use Union that makes the variable to be either a np.ndarray or a torch.Tensor
from typing import Union
MyData: Union[np.ndarray, torch.Tensor]


Ok thanks. What is the difference between "Union[]" and the "|" I used in the example above?

They do the same thing for specifying multiple types. However, | is available in Python 3.10 and later, while Union can be used if you are working with older versions of Python.
